# Add multiple attachments over custom list item using javascript

Tags: custom-list, list-item, attachments

Is there a limitation for the attachments that can be added over a custom list against each item in SP2013 online?

If not, am I stuck over a scenario where I need to add more than 2 different files against each list item?

Comment: these files will always be the same? where are you storing these files?

Comment: I want to save that as an attachment for list items .

Comment: Is that using rest API i can be able to add attachments to listItem?

Comment: Yes, you can use rest api..but you didn't answer my question..where are the files you want to attach located?

Comment: It needs to be associates with the custom list item.

Comment: I get that.i am asking is about the files you are going to attach! Will the user select those files or you always going to attach the same two files to the list item

Comment: just think in this way , it is like creating new candidate info to the  list and attaching its resume , photo  to same item as an attachments. Can you suggest me how i can achieve this .?

Answer (score 0):

There probably is no limit:

[Sharepoint List Item Attachment Limitation](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/bd512e45-6b62-4fab-aa7c-7adf5a90a97c/sharepoint-list-item-attachment-limitation)

But adding attachments via javascript might be tricky. I tried that once and had to use powershell instead.

Comment: Ok , its highly considerable that list items not having any limit for adding attachments to it. But how to add it , and identify those attachments using javascript.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot add attachments via javascript

Comment: I am calling its OOB feature for uploading the file to list in my js code using  SP dialog URl- "siteUrl+"/_layouts/Attachfile.aspx?ListId={" + ListId+ "}&ItemId=" + itemId; It is working for single attachments, and looking forward to perform the same for multiple items.
"

Comment: So you open a dialogue? I thought you tried to do this automatically

Comment: Yes @Nils its opening OOB dialog for uploading the attachments, and it associate it with the list .

Comment: um, ok, so what's your problem now?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [blog](http://techfindings-prem.blogspot.com.br/2014/11/uploading-multiple-attachments-to-lists.html).

I made the same code in three different projects and it worked perfectly.

You will need a jQuery.Multifile library to follow the example.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a ref from the below link.

Just need to modify the html as per the requirement . 
[Link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-2013-uploading-multiple-attachments-to-the-new-item-on-list-using-j/)